# Can't find request module even if its installed python django

Tags: python, django, directory

I'm making a django website, in one of my scripts, I import the requests module. I've installed the requests module with my virtual environnement but I can't import it in my scripts. I have already tried to install and desinstall it. My request module is installed in ProjectFolder.env\Lib\site-packages\requests and my script is located in the folder ProjectFolder\app_name\matches\get_matches.py
The strangest part is that I can import other modules that are installed in this folder in my scripts but not request in particular.
Do you know what could be the origin of the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Do you for some reason have named a file `requests.py`?

Comment: No, but there is a file named requests.py in django preinstalled module

Comment: not in the Django preinstalled module, but in your own web server implementation.

Comment: Ok so what do you think I should do in order to make it work?